# Make Array of Ranges when Range is too Big

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a macro which takes a column and splits it into multiple columns of 444 because my range max is 444 rows. How can I then iterate over each column and assign a range ideally with the same name, but in an array format.

I'm also open to removing the idea of splitting the column and just having something like `for each 444 rows, create rng.` Then `for each rng in rng.arry` Do XYZ.

Update: Basically I have a row with 1000 values. I'd like to have an array of ranges with the format like so:

```
rng(0) = A1:A444
rng(1) = A445:A889
rng(2) = A890:A1000
```

Then I can loop through each rng like so:

```
For each rng in rng.array
   ... Do Stuff
End For
```

Here is what I have to split the column, but I looked up about arrays of ranges and couldn't find anything.

```
 Sub Four_Hundred_Fourty_Four_Split_Sub()
Dim lastRow As Long, copynumRow As Long
Dim cRow As Long, cCol As Long
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range

If IsEmpty(urng) = False Then
Debug.Print urng
Set urng = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)
End If
Set rng = Range(Col_Letter(urng.Column) & "1:" & Col_Letter(urng.Column) & Cells(Rows.Count, urng.Column).End(xlUp).Row)

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set sSheet = ActiveSheet

WorksheetCreate ("444_Split")
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("444_Split")
sSheet.Select


rng.Copy Destination:=ws.Range(Col_Letter(urng.Column) & "1:" & Col_Letter(urng.Column) & Cells(Rows.Count, urng.Column).End(xlUp).Row)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

copynumRow = 444
cCol = 2
cRow = 1 + copynumRow

With ws
    lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Do While cRow <= lastRow
        .Range("A" & cRow).Resize(copynumRow, 1).Cut _
            Destination:=.Cells(1, cCol).Resize(copynumRow, 1)

        cRow = cRow + copynumRow
        cCol = cCol + 1
    Loop
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

ws.Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Why "my range max is 444 rows"? Can you better explain (in words) what you want accomplishing? Try, please edit your question and show us a picture (if not something editable) with the situation as it is and another one with what you need to accomplish. It looks difficult to understand your need. At least, for me...

Comment: What do you mean by "array format" - do you want actual arrays rather then cell ranges?

Comment: Actually, your use of `rng(0) = A1:A444` suggests you want an array of ranges. What's the problem with the current code - does it error or not do what you want?

Comment: @SJR I had this code from before, when I did it manually and just used this to generate a WS with each column having a max of 444, but good point, I can probably adapt what I need inside the `Do While` loop. I'll give that a go and post update/answer.

Comment: I was asking about the reason which makes the "max 444 rows" necessity in order to look together for some other alternatives... About making an array of ranges, it is not so complicated. I did such a sub last evening (evening in my country), just for fun, but I thought it will be good to understand which is your goal, not a step where you maybe are stacked...

Comment: I can see that you received an answer. I will post mine, too, since I do not need such a code and did it only for you, if no better alternative will be found...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sketched something out, which works for your example. I've added a few comments to explain, but have not tested thoroughly.

I'd advise using more meaningful variable names etc.

This produces an array of ranges, which could then be transferred back to the worksheet.

```
Sub x()

Dim r As Range, rStart As Range
Dim n As Long, i As Long, j As Long
Dim r1() As Range

n = 444

Set r = Range("A1:A1000")
ReDim r1(1 To WorksheetFunction.Ceiling(r.Count / n, 1)) 'work out how many groups of 444

For i = 1 To UBound(r1)
    Set rStart = r.Cells((i - 1) * n + 1) 'starting cell of each array element
    If r(r.Rows.Count).Row - rStart.Row < n Then    'check if less than 444 rows left
        j = r(r.Rows.Count).Row - rStart.Row + 1
    Else
        j = n
    End If
    Set r1(i) = rStart.Resize(j) 'expand group to full size and add to array
    Debug.Print r1(i).Address
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I'll have to test, I got it working with my code, but it's old and ugly and confusing to me, and I wrote it!

Comment: This is great, I have a hard time following the `((i - 1) * n + 1)` logic, but I bet if I wrote it, it would make sense why. Originally like I said, I used my macro to paste results to a new sheet, but really, I want to do something else now that doesn't involve WS's so this is much cleaner and easy to adjust for different #'s. I'm impeded by other softwares rate limit when retrieving data via vba and I have to make `loop code` to get around it.

Comment: Probably easiest to work out what it means for each value of `i`, so when i=1, (i-1)=0 and this resolves to `r.cells(1)`. When i=2 this is `r.cells(445)` so it advances us through the range in steps of 444.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up using for now at the bottom of my code above, but I don't say it's the best way at all....

```
WS.Select
Call FindLast(WS)

Dim rcell As Range

Set rng = Application.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:" & lColLet & "1")

For Each rcell In rng.Cells
 If Not IsError(rcell.Value) Then
  If rcell.Value <> "" Then
    Set IDRng = WS.Range(rcell.Address, rcell.End(xlDown))
    Call PasteInWV
  End If
 End If
Next rcell

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, test the next code, too. Test it on a new empty sheet, where it will build a test range of 1000 rows, for a column chosen by you and returns each array range in other columns starting from the 5th one:

```
Sub testRangesArray()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, arrR As Variant, lastRow As Long, Lcol As String, splitVal As Long
  Dim i As Long, k As Long, rng As Range
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  Lcol = "B" 'Column to be processed/tested letter
  'Create a test range in the test column________________________________________________
    With sh.Range(Lcol & "2:" & Lcol & 3)
        .Value = Application.Transpose(Array(1, 2))
        .AutoFill Destination:=sh.Range(Lcol & "2:" & Lcol & "1001"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    End With
  '______________________________________________________________________________________
  
  lastRow = sh.Range(Lcol & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
  Set rng = sh.Range(Lcol & "2:" & Lcol & lastRow)
  splitVal = 444 'you may set here what you need

  ReDim arrR(WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(rng.Rows.count / splitVal, 0) - 1)
  For i = 0 To UBound(arrR)
    Set arrR(i) = Range(Lcol & IIf(i = 0, rng.Cells(1).row, splitVal * i + rng.Cells(1).row) & ":" & _
                          IIf(i = UBound(arrR), Lcol & rng.Rows.count + rng.Cells(1).row - 1, Lcol & _
                                                            splitVal * (i + 1) + rng.Cells(1).row - 1))
  Next i
  'Drop the array ranges values in columns, starting from the 5th one:
  For i = 0 To UBound(arrR)
    sh.Cells(1, 5 + i).Resize(arrR(i).Rows.count, 1).Value = arrR(i).Value
  Next
End Sub
```